# How do I make thunderbird auto-start everytime I log in in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to have thunderbird mail running as soon as I turn on both of my PCs I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.14 however when i go to the startup menu it's empty, I can click add to add a program startup, unfortunately I do not have the thunderbird command line and as you know (The startup command cannot be empty) please help me thank you.

Comment: the thunderbird command is ... `thunderbird` :) (without the smile)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the command to start thunderbird. That would be `/usr/bin/thunderbird`

Comment: since thunderbird is in $PATH, no need to add `/usr/bin/`